# Show that $\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{1}{r^2}\int_{C_{r}}f(z)dz = 2 \pi i\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}(z_0)$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Well, after spending hours on this problem, I'm still stuck, so I thought I'd turn to you guys. The problem statement is as follows.

Let $f$ be a complex-valued function that is $C^1$ in the disk $|z - z_0| < R$ for some $R>0$, and let $C_r$ be the circle $|z - z_0| = r$. Show that $$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{1}{r^2}\int_{C_{r}}f(z)dz = 2 \pi i\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}(z_0).$$

I tried parametrizing the circle in the usual way and differentiating to see if I get something useful, but no luck. I just can't get the LHS to give me something to do with $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}$, so that I could then put the RHS under the integral and show that the difference between the two can be less than arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ by the continuity of partial derivatives.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: @Dr.MV Good thing that $\partial{f}/\partial \overline{z}$ is zero in that case as well.

Comment: @Dr.MV $\partial/\partial\overline{z}$ is a common notation for $(\partial/\partial x+\textrm{i}\partial/\partial y)/2$ so $\partial{f}/\partial \overline{z}=0$ by the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Wait, so what's wrong with the question that it got downvoted?

Comment: @Ryker My guess: someone who didn't understand your question. Stuff like this happens on m.se.

Comment: Ah OK, I thought it had something to do with my wording.

Comment: @WimC Yes, I know that.  That was my point.  $f$ is analytic and has no functional dependence on $z^*$.

Comment: By the way, if the LHS is zero, that also seems to imply the function is differentiable (this is without assuming $f$ is $C^1$, of course), although I don't quite get why. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Morera's Theorem answers that.

Comment: @Ryker I saw your question received a down vote.  I gave you an up vote to compensate.

Comment: @Dr.MV, is there another, easier way to show the above is true without Morera's Theorem? Also, Morera's Theorem doesn't really address that, because here we have an additional factor of $\frac{1}{r^2}$ and the limit, no? And thanks for the upvote :)

Comment: @Ryker Mere continuity won't do it. Let $f=(\bar z - \bar z_0)^n$ where $n$ is an integer with $n\ge2$.  Clearly, $f$ is continuous in $C_r$.  And $\int_{C_r} f dz=0$ for all $r$.  Thus, the limit of interest is zero and yet $f$ is nowhere differentiable.

Comment: @Dr.MV, you're absolutely right. I thought the question required me to work without the assumption that $f$ is $C^1$ for that part, and I made that mistake because I also immediately jumped to the conclusion that $C^1$ implies complex differentiable. But assuming $f$ is $C^1$, that follows immediately from the definition of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}$, since the function will then also satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: @Dr.MV, no, but that's not true, as Umberto already mentioned in the comments to his answer (and as the book I'm using would also agree). $C^1$ is not the same as holomorphic.

Comment: @Dr.MV, you could have a $C^1$ function that does not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, and I don't see anything in those notes that would contradict that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is convenient to use little-o notation. Apply the Taylor estimate for complex functions. If $f$ is $C^1$ in a neighborhood of $z_0$ then $$f(z) = f(z_0) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial  z}(z_0) (z - z_0) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} (z_0) (\bar z - \bar z_0) + o(|z - z_0|).$$

According to Cauchy's theorem you have $$\int_{C_r} f(z) \, dz = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} (z_0) \int_{C_r} (\bar z - \bar z_0) \, dz + \int_{C_r} o(|z - z_0|) dz.$$

The latter integrals can be parameterized using $z = z_0 + re^{it}$.  Then $\bar z - \bar z_0 = r e^{-it}$ and $dz = ire^{it}$ so that
$$\int_{C_r} (\bar z - \bar z_0) \, dz = \int_0^{2\pi} re^{-it} i re^{it} \, dt = 2\pi i r^2$$

and
$$\left| \int_{C_r} o(|z - z_0|) dz \right|\le \int_{C_r} o(|z - z_0|) |dz| = \int_0^{2\pi} o(r) r \,dt = 2\pi r^2 \frac{o(r)}{r}.$$
Thus
$$\frac{1}{r^2} \int_{C_r} f(z) \, dz = 2\pi i \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} (z_0) + 2\pi \frac{o(r)}{r}.$$

---

Comment on notation: we can express points $z \in \mathbb C$ as $z = x + iy$.  Then $\bar z = x - iy$, $x = \frac 12 (z + \bar z)$ and $y = -\frac i2 (z - \bar z)$. The $z$ and $\bar z$ derivatives of $f$ are defined formally via the chain rule: $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial z} = \frac 12[ f_x - i f_y]$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial \bar z} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial \bar z} = \frac 12[ f_x + i f_y].$$

If $f$ is analytic then $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z} = f'(z)$ and $\dfrac{\partial f} {\partial \bar z} = 0$.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check your answer in detail in a bit, but I think I was supposed to do this without resorting to Cauchy's Theorem (although I can't see where you've actually used it here, since it seems to be straight-up integration of both sides). In the book that I'm using, the latter namely only appears in the later chapters, so do you know another way to do it? Can I take $f(z_0) = 0$, WLOG? I *think* I can, and I *think* that could be useful, but I haven't fully worked it out yet.

Comment: Cauchy's theorem isn't really necessary. A straight calculation shows that $$\int_{C_r} f(z_0) \, dz = \int_{C_r} (z - z_0) \, dz = 0.$$

Comment: Hmm, how did you get that first equality in the comment you just made? I mean, $f(z_0)$ is a constant function, so you could just integrate it directly by finding its antiderivative $f(z_0)z$ and then evaluate it around a closed loop (so that it's indeed $0$), no?

Comment: Yes, both integrals are zero.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, for some reason I thought $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}(z_0) = \lim_{{h} \to 0} \frac{f(z_0 + h) - f(z_0)}{\bar{h}}$, but this is not true, is it?

Comment: Also, shouldn't you have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(z_0) (z - z_0)$ in the first line of your Taylor expansion?

Comment: Yeah, a cut-and-paste error.

Comment: Alright, cool. Any input on that additional question in the comments perhaps?

Comment: I will add some notation to the answer.

Comment: I understood your notation, but I still can't quite convince myself of the answer to my question. At first I namely thought that equality would hold, but now I'm having doubts. This is unrelated to your argument, but if it held I might have another way of doing this problem. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: But $f$ is not analytic.

Comment: @Ryker Try $f(z) = z$. Then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} = 0$, but $\frac{f(z_0 + h) - f(z_0)}{\bar h} = \frac{h}{\bar h}$ which has no limit as $h \to 0$.

Comment: No it does not. $C^1$ means that the partial derivatives in the $x$ and $y$ directions exist and are continuous.

Comment: @UmbertoP., thanks for that example, and I don't know why I was thinking that would be the case in the first place.